# Search in GET with a multifield condition

Tags: elasticsearch, search, get

I would like to perform an elasticsearch query relying on a GET request.

This query successfully allow me to see all the messages inside the index addressed to a particular sender (i.e., where *sender.id == some value*).

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/messages/_search?q=sender.id:user1
```

Now, I would like to add a new field. In my case study, to retrieve only the messages with the boolean flag *received set to true*. So I tried:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/messages/_search?q=sender.id:user1&received:true
```

But this doesn't work, and I can't find any documentation / example on how to perform a GET query with multifield.

Please note that the parameter *received* exists, is always set, and is correctly working when used alone.

Comment: You can do it with POST request and `bool query` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Comment: The question is about a GET context, there is a reason for that. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `q` parameter take the lucene query syntax.

So to add another condition use the following:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex/messages/_search?q=sender.id:user1%20AND%20received:true
```

Comment: Perfect. I also found the documentation section that cover this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field